# why is iterator object not created with new keyword for list collection in Java

Tags: java, object, iterator, instance, new-operator

I came across this bit of code to remove strings of even length from given Linked list
I don't understand why the iterator object `itr` not instantiated with `new` keyword. here is the code..

```
public static void removeEvenLength(List<String> list) {
     Iterator<String> itr= list.iterator();
     while (itr.hasNext()) {
         String element=itr.next();
         if (element.length()%2==0) {
             i.remove();
     }
   }
}
```

Does it mean here, that the iterator method is `static` and it just returns a new `iterable object` with `list` as its `field`. can someone provide with me one or more examples where similar way of instantiating is encountered in Java other than singleton constructors I suppose.
Thank you

Comment: `list.iterator()` is a simple non-static method in `List` that returns an iterator instance - why the confusion ?

Comment: Um, have you not noticed that methods return things? By your logic the only return type ever used for a method would be `void`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does it mean here, that the iterator method is static and it just returns a new iterable object with list as its field.

No, it's an instance method. It just returns a reference to an `Iterator<String>`. So the body of the `iterator()` method is likely to *contain* a `new` statement (although it's possible that it in turn calls on to something else). Let's take it away from iterators and generics for now - a similar situation is:

```
class Bar {}

class Foo {
    Bar createBar() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Bar bar = foo.createBar();
    }
}
```

Same pattern: an instance method which returns a new instance of a different type.

Comment: These can also be called `Instance factory` method.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks. if the body of the `iterator()` method contains `new`, the `list` object on which the `iterator` is called should become the field for it, or else on what am I going to iterate through?

Comment: @user1988876: Well it *might* use some internal data structure within the list - but it would probably have a reference to the list itself, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Not every object is created *explicitly* with a `new` keyword. A method can internally create a new object, do some things to it, and return it.

Depending on the type of `List` the iterator is usually a private inner class, called `Itr` in the ArrayList. It is instantiated in `iterator(`. For the `ArrayList` example, that method reads as follows:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

Other classes implementing `List` can either use a different private inner class, or may, in certain (non-jre, usually) implementations use an anonymous class.

Answer (score 1):

It's not instantiated with the new operator because `list.iterator` is not a type, but a method that returns an object that is instantiated within the method. it's merely assigned to the return value of that method.